# Passing value params from one method to another method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method: index that gets the value of the checkbox per post

```
def index
  session[:post] = params[:checkbox_array]
end
```

The value of `params[:checkbox_array]` is:

```
{"2m"=>"1", "2"=>"2", "3m"=>"3", "3"=>"4", "4"=>"5", "4a_5d"=>"6", "5"=>"7", "6m"=>"8", "6"=>"9", "7m"=>"10", "7"=>"11"}
```

When I click on button to make the post I am redirect to page *interval_identification.html*

I want to get the variable value `@post` on method `interval_identification` on controller.

I can not call the `index` method inside the `interval_identification` method because I'm going to do a get in the `interval_identification` and the value of the `@post` variable should be the same when the post was done in the `index`.

I was researching and saw that the solution would be to save the `@post` value of the method `index` in the session, and then reading that value and assigning it to a variable in the `interval_identification` method, but I do not know how to do that, can you help me?

```
def interval_identification
  @post = session[:post]
end
```

I tried to do it. but when I show the @post value on interval_identification view, the value is blank

interval_identification.html.erb:

`<a><%= @post %></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the session is pretty straight forward:

```
def index
  session[:post] = params[:checkbox_array]
end

def interval_identification
  #session[:post] should be here waiting for you!
end
```

Comment: I tried: `@post = session[:post]` on "interval_identification" But I can not see the `<%= @post %>` value in the view interval_identification

Comment: @Maktube can you update your question to include the new code for your `index` and `interval_identification` methods?

Comment: I want the @post variable in the "interval_identification" to get the value of the post from the "index"

Comment: @Maktube add the following lines to help with debugging. In your `index` method, just above the assignment, put: `puts "params: #{params[:checkbox_array]}"`. And in your `interval_identification` method, put: `puts "session: #{session[:post]}"`. Run your code and show me what the console output is.

Comment: Started POST "/site/ear_master/interval_identification" 
Processing by Site::EarMasterController#interval_identification as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VmRcVf7OSlgXTWTZKEVIsRL38nWMPNgMJO5ffrq67UIR2/xqfYtIqVP3HmYUlO3FEFFfllkcuvOa3BjlUSiDjw==", "checkbox_array"=>{"2m"=>"1", "2"=>"2", "3m"=>"3", "3"=>"4", "4"=>"5", "4a_5d"=>"6", "5"=>"7", "6m"=>"8", "6"=>"9", "7m"=>"10", "7"=>"11"}, "commit"=>"OK"}
session: 
Completed 200 OK in 62ms (Views: 61.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: session is blank

Comment: def index
    session[:post] = params[:checkbox_array]
    puts "params: #{params[:checkbox_array]}"
end


 def interval_identification
    @post = session[:post]
    puts "session: #{session[:post]}"
end

Comment: @Maktube I see you accepted my answer- did you get it working?